# iOS: Reverse AVPlayer playback till the beginning, without invoking AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification

Tags: ios, avplayer, reverse, playback

I received a request to override what is currently an intended behaviour on iOS/tvOS and I'm having trouble getting it to work.

As the title says, I like to make it so reversing playback till the beginning without triggering the notification that the playback has ended. This is a snippet of the code I have.

```
AVPlayer player = [self generatePlayer];
playerItem = [self generatePlayerItem];
//playerItem.reversePlaybackEndTime = kCMTimeInvalid;
[player replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem]
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerItemDidReachEnd:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:player.currentItem];
[player play];
...
//on rewind
player.rate = -1;
....
//upon currentTime = 0 on rewind, playerItemDidReachEnd is called
```

I need advice on what code to be changed here so it will accomplish what I want. I thought that the `reversePlaybackEndTime` property is the answer but it doesn't let me set a negative `CMTime` in it.